# How to get title of youtube video from the id of the video for our android app?

Tags: android, kotlin, youtube-api, youtubeplayer

I have been developing a simple app for practicing.
The app includes fetching of youtube videos. I am using  this https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player  (using this for editing the Youtube Player View, as youtube official api doesn't allowed to do so) library. Now I also want to fetch the title of the video but can't think of how to do this so.

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can get video info in json or XML format using this query: 
https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=youtube.com/watch?v=7QU1nvuxaMA&format=json 
You just need to set `url` and `format`.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can  use the Youtube Data API v3 for getting the details in the form of json and then we request any details of the video which are not restricted using the API Key.
for the API key we can go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and create a project by adding SHA1 fingerprint of your app.
and https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started got to this for getting the API and use any software like Postman for checking the details by getting json file.

and then we are good to go :-)